# How many foreign keys is too many?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, foreign-keys

After running across this article:
http://diovo.com/2008/08/are-foreign-keys-really-necessary-in-a-database-design/

It seems like a good idea to use foreign keys when designing a database. But when are you using too many?

For example, suppose I have a main table used to store a list of machinery part information that other programs make reference to with the following columns:

1. ID
2. Name
3. Colour
4. Price
5. Measurement Units
6. Category
7. etc...

Should I be making tables containing a list of all possible colours, units and categories and then setting these as foreign keys to the corresponding columns in my machine part info table? At what point would the benefit of using foreign keys out weight the fact that I'm making all these extra tables and relationships?

Comment: depends.... maybe colors,  remember that people can spell things wrong and you might want to search for it easily.  probably not units since you can just use an int.  most of the time anything that fits under "categories" is good to keep in another table and do a FK reference.  it just depends.  there are pro's and con's to both relational DB design and flat table/file design... it could depend on what DB you're using, too, or the code around it... just do what seems to make sense in the long run.

Comment: a benefit of relationships is not storing the same data over and over again... consider the size of different data types.  a numerical reference to a varchar(max) is going to save space.  but if you're working in access or if your surrounding code can handle fixed lists for you - maybe color isn't something you want a separate table for.

Comment: I think the big question that gets you to the heart of "too many" is, are you doing a lot of inserts into this table?  If you are, then all of those foreign keys will need to be checked against their tables to ensure they are valid.  That isn't a free operation.  I'm guessing something like a parts catalog doesn't get many inserts, though, and it wouldn't impact your database's performance severely.

Comment: So if I were to have another table that only kept records of say... on-going projects and entries are constantly being added/removed, then it would be a bad idea to have foreign keys? Would it be okay for some foreign keys for cascade deletes, for example?

Comment: Perhaps a deeper understanding of database normalization, especially 3rd normal form would be helpful to you - just Google 3NF.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Any attribute for which you want to be able to state, with certainty, that there are only known, valid values present in the database should be protected with a foreign key.  Otherwise, you can only hope to catch invalid values in your application code and whatever interfaces are created in the future.

It is NOT a bad thing to have more tables and relationships.  The only issue -- and it usually is not one -- has to do with the overhead of maintaining the indexes that are used in enforcing those relationships.  Until you experience performance issues you should create a foreign key relationship for every column that "should" have one (because the values need to be validated against a list).

The performance considerations would have to be pretty dire before I would be willing to sacrifice correctness for performance.

Comment: Note that FK's are obviously useful and should be used, but they are not your only option when it comes to data validation. Check constraints are certainly valid and should be used when the values are discreet, do not change as a matter of business logic, and have no other information associated with them.

Comment: That is certainly true.  I was hoping not to confuse the issue.  The examples cited by the OP all seem to be better handled via foreign keys.  Also, check constraints are slightly less portable across database in my experience (although that may not matter depending on what your development environment is like).

Answer (score 4):

Every Design is a compromise of competing goals, so there are very few simple answers (except the wrong ones).

I would certainly put discrete measures such as name, color, category, measure unit, etc.. in their own key tables.  Variable measures (cost, number of units ,etc..) not so much, unless you have units in standard size packages (i.e. only 1, 6, 12, etc..)

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to design a database is to start with the requirements.  In one classical methodology, the requirements are summarized in an ER (Entity-Relationship) model.  In this model, relationships between entities are not invented, they are discovered.  If they lie within the scope of the information the database is supposed to cover, then they are part of the model.  Period.

From there, when you turn to database design,  you already know what relationships you need.  You have a few decisions to make about the structure of your tables, but almost all the foreign keys that reference a primary key are a direct consequence of the requirements.

Of course, if you are at liberty to change the requirements as you go through the design process, then you can do anything you want.

Answer (score 1):

Dimensional modelling covers all points of your question well. Having too many foreign key relationships can make query performance suffer. Kimball's Group Reader is a great introduction to Dimensional Design and how to translate customer requirements to a schema.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_modeling

The main question to ask is 'how constrained does the data need to be?' Concerning the color of machine parts, I'd assume, it would be in everyone's best interest not to have burnt ciena and camomille as color options. So, a look up table for these would be best.

Comment: Just to clarify, whether or not there's a foreign key (meaning the same level of normalization with or without a foreign key) won't affect *query* performance. It will affect *DML* operations, but not querying.

Comment: I should have been clearer, I was speaking to using a lookup or adding it as part of the dimension. But yes, same level of normalization wouldn't make a difference.